# renumbering values to be consecutive

Tags: loops, while-loop

I am working with bioinformatics data. I have a sequence of repetitive numbers that are nonconsecutive in nature. I am trying to find a simple way to renumber them so that they are consecutive.

Ex:

old: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 5 5 7 7 7 9 9

Desire change

new: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 6 6

I'm using R.

Comment: which programming language you use for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can solve this is by using a for loop and keeping track of the current number you are inserting and the value you are replacing.

```
vec <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9)
curr <- vec[1]
rep <- vec[1]

for(i in 1:length(vec)) {
  if(vec[i] > rep) {
    rep <- vec[i]
    curr <- curr + 1
  }

  if(vec[i] > curr) {
    vec[i] <- curr
  }
}

# Print the results
for(val in vec) {
  print(val)
}
```

This solution assumes that the numbers are already sorted. If not, you can use the [sort](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sort.html) method.